# Angular FormArray value as an array, not object

Tags: angular

I want to convert the values of "trackings" to an array. Right now, it prints an object. See below:

[image]

I need **trackings** to be an array: trackings: ['value','value']

Below my current code:

```
interface FormInterface {
  items: [{
    sku: string;
    quantity: string;
    received: string;
    trackings: Array < any > ;
  }];
  orderId: string;
  isPrime: boolean;
  reason: string;
}

addItemToForm() {
  const items = this.fb.group({
    sku: ['', Validators.required],
    quantity: ['', Validators.required],
    received: ['', Validators.required],
    trackings: this.fb.array([])
  });
  this.itemsForm.push(items);
}

addTrackingsToForm(control) {
  console.log(control);
  control.push(
    this.fb.group({
      trackings: [] as Array < any >
    })
  );
}

submitData() {
  console.log( < FormInterface > this.inputData.value);
  // this.returns.createReturn(this.inputData.value).subscribe(data => {
  //   this.returns.openSnackBar('Return Created!', '');
  //   this.inputData.reset();
  // });
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your stackblitz was giving errors in console, I could not debug them... I created this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-us6byj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ... see if helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `addTrackingsToForm` is adding a `FormGroup` to the `FormArray`. It should be adding a `FormControl` instead. Change it to `control` instead of `array` in that case:

```
addTrackingsToForm(control) {
    console.log(control);
    control.push(
      this.fb.control()
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hey. If I add control instead of group, then the tree changes: 'items -> 0 -> trackings -> 0 -> trackings' when it needs to be: items -> 0 -> trackings -> 0'

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a Stackblitz?

Comment: I tried, but the template does not want to work. If you want to take a look at the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bjvrxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I've literally spent an hour building such a form a few days back. You might want to have a look at it here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-complex-reactive-form

Comment: I will take a look at it. Thanks!